# IndexError in a python list - "list index out of range"

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to get certain data in columns from my MySQL database but I get this error when trying to index a list in a for loop. Everything works well until I'm trying to print out data from 1 column.

Here's the list. I do believe this is a tuple but that shouldn't be the problem. (I think)

```
(1, 'Router', '192.168.1.1', '80')
```

Here's my code:

```
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
            for x in myresult:
                print(x)
                time.sleep(0.2)
            ip = myresult[2]
            print(ip)
```

This is the IndexError:

```
.....
File "directory..", line 172, in huvudmeny2
    ip = myresult[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can it be out of range when it has 4 items?

Comment: `fetchall()` returns a list of tuples not a single tuple. If you have only one result, that will be a list with one item (which will be the the tuple in question). Your ip is probably at `x[2]` for each result.

Comment: How many actual rows are being found by this query? Because `myresult[2]` is trying to get the third row of the results.

Comment: Oh, I see! Is there any other way I could access the IP column? Thanks for the quick reply.@MarkM

Comment: @khelwood There is only 1 row. I basically thought that I could access the third item in the list and not the row!

Comment: redeliish, since you want the third item of the tuple, which is the first item in the list, that would be `myresult[0][2]` - see my answer for a more detailed response.

Comment: @redeliish if you only expect one row, maybe `fetchone()`  is a better choice here. Then you just get the tuple you are looking for and can index it the way you like.

Comment: @MarkM, that's a good idea, I've added it to the accepted answer. The only caveat is that you need to watch out for an empty result set, but OP has to do that anyway, even for `fetchall`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetchall` method returns a list of the remaining rows, each a tuple. It does not return the tuple.

Hence there's a good chance you got less than three rows.

If you want the IP address of the first row from the query (for example), that would be:

```py
myresult[0][2]
```

The following transcript shows this in action (after dummying up some data):

```py
>>> myresult = [(1, 'Router', '192.168.1.1', '80')]

>>> print(myresult)
[(1, 'Router', '192.168.1.1', '80')]

>>> print(myresult[2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

>>> print(myresult[0][2])
192.168.1.1
```

---

An alternative, if you know there will only be one row of useful data, is to use `fetchone` instead of `fetchall`. This actually returns a single tuple rather than a list of tuples, so you can use your original indexing method. You just need to check for `None` first since that's what you'll get if there were *no* rows returned.

But you already *have* that problem since you're not checking for an empty list in your original code, which is what `fetchall` gives you when there are no rows.

Comment: Thank you, answered my question. So a small recap.. the "[0]" is targeting the row and [2] is targeting the index item? Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @redeliish: I *will* correct you if you're wrong, that's in my nature. However, since you're right, all I can do is applaud you for understanding :-)

Answer (score 1):

`fetchall()` returns a list, so you are printing index 2 of this list.

maybe you want something like:

```
for x in myresult:
  print(x)
  time.sleep(0.2)
ip = myresult[0][2]
print(ip)
```

So you will access the 1st element of the list of tuples, then access the element you want.

You also can put the last 2 lines in the for loop to make sure they exist, like so:

```
for x in myresult:
  print(x)
  time.sleep(0.2)
  ip = myresult[2]
  print(ip)
```